# Does the GUIStyle.hover state apply to Unity Editor labels (or other controls besides Button)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am creating a custom editor window in Unity.  I want to have a label change color when the mouse hovers over it.  To accomplish this, it would seem that this should work:

```cs
GUI.skin.label.hover.textColor = Color.red;
GUILayout.Label("My Label");
```

But the label still displays as normal with no effect when I hover over it with the mouse.

I've also tried manually creating GUIStyles and passing them as an argument to GUILayout.Label with the same result.  If I change the `normal` state, however, I see the color change.

Is the `hover` state supported for labels, and if not, what controls is it supported for and how would I find out this information?  It seems absent from Unity's docs.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `GUI.skin.button` if you are only interested in changing the text color.

```
var myStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
myStyle.hover.textColor = Color.red;
GUILayout.Label("My Label", myStyle);
```

However, this has the side effect of taking all of the other qualities of the button style. Your label will look like a button. In theory you could change the background image for all of the style states and make it look not like a button, but doing so for the `normal` state reverts the hover behavior to that of a label style. [This answer](https://discussions.unity.com/t/guilayout-button-hover-texture-not-changing-immediately/197385) in the unity Q&A seems to be the most insightful explanation for why `hover` does not work (at least, not usually) but `normal` and `active` do.

In short, unity has special code for built in GUI styles that have hover over effects that force a redraw when the mouse passes over them. This seems to somehow be tied up in the `normal` style state for certain special styles, such as `GUI.skin.button`. The result, there is no option to have custom hover backgrounds, and anything that does need to have a custom hover text color must have the same background image as one of the built-in button styles.

Comment: In my opinion, this is one of the larger holes in unity's editor style extensibility. I would love to see it fixed, but likely the entire GUIStyle system needs to be redesigned, so I can understand why it hasn't been fixed yet.